# Conditionally remove key from map

Tags: groovy

I want to conditionally remove a collection, if the value is a given text, or null.

For a simple example below:

```
def map1 = [
        1: "#NULL",
        2: [
                2.1: "some value",
                2.2: "some value"
        ]]

assert map1.dropWhile { key, value ->
    value.equals("#NULL") || value == null
} == [2: [2.1: "some value", 2.2: "some value"]]
```

However, this drop while does not deal with sub level key and value. The below one will fail the assertion:

```
def map2 = [
        1: "#NULL",
        2: [
                2.1: "#NULL",
                2.2: "some value"
        ]]

assert map2.dropWhile { key, value ->
    value.equals("#NULL") || value == null
} == [2: [2.2: "some value"]]
```

Is there a way to do this?

---

Updated after Tim's answer
Now the below script will work well:

```
def defaultMap = [
        1: "some value",
        2: [
                2.1: "some value",
                2.2: "some value",
                2.3: [
                        "2.3.1": "some value",
                        "2.3.2": " some value"
                ]
        ]
]

def replacementMap = [2: [2.4: "some other value"]]

assert defaultMap.collectEntries(replacementMap) { mapKey, mapValue ->
    [mapKey, replacementMap.containsKey(mapKey) ? replacementMap[mapKey] : mapValue] // Remove default key and value pairs, if they are present in the replacement map.
                                                                                     // New key and value pairs in the replacement map will be preserved
}.collectEntries { mapKey, mapValue ->
    switch (mapValue) {
        case Map:
            return [mapKey, { -> mapValue.collectEntries owner }()]
        case '#NULL': // Remove key, if the value is also TEXT #NULL
            return [:]
        default:
            [mapKey, mapValue]
    }
} == [2: [2.4: 'some other value'], 1: 'some value']
```

However, if I want to nullify a submap, but keep all the other sub map on the same level, it is not working properly:

```
def defaultMap = [
        1: "some value",
        2: [
                2.1: "some value",
                2.2: "some value",
                2.3: [
                        "2.3.1": "some value",
                        "2.3.2": " some value"
                ]
        ]
]

def replacementMap = [2.3: '#NULL']

assert defaultMap.collectEntries(replacementMap) { mapKey, mapValue ->
    [mapKey, replacementMap.containsKey(mapKey) ? replacementMap[mapKey] : mapValue] // Remove default key and value pairs, if they are present in the replacement map.
                                                                                     // New key and value pairs in the replacement map will be preserved
}.collectEntries { mapKey, mapValue ->
    switch (mapValue) {
        case Map:
            return [mapKey, { -> mapValue.collectEntries owner }()]
        case '#NULL': // Remove key, if the value is also TEXT #NULL
            return [:]
        default:
            [mapKey, mapValue]
    }
} == [1:'some value', 2:[2.1:'some value', 2.2:'some value', 2.3:null]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a simple recursive map walker:

```
def map2 = [
    '1': "#NULL",
    '2': [
        '2.1': "#NULL",
        '2.2': "some value"
    ]
]

def result = map2.collectEntries { name, value ->
    switch(value) {
        case Map:
            return [name, { -> value.collectEntries owner }()]
        case '#NULL':
            return [:]
        default:
            [name, value]
    }
}

assert result == ['2':['2.2':'some value']]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tim, most of it is working well apart from one scenario that I have updated in the description, are you able to take another look to see if you have any more input? Appreciate your help :)

Comment: I have no idea what your edit is supposed to mean. What's the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a recursive method:

```
def map2 = [
        1: "#NULL",
        2: [
                2.1: "#NULL",
                2.2: "some value"
        ]
]

def dropRecursive(Map m) {
    m.dropWhile { k, v ->
        if (v in Map) {
            m[k] = dropRecursive(v)
            return false
        } else {
            v == null || '#NULL'.equals(v)
        }
    }
}

assert dropRecursive(map2) == [2: [2.2: "some value"]]
```

It's required to use `return false` in case of processing a `Map` since the result will be projected to `boolean` expression. Since non empty `Map` is `true` in groovy it will be removed as well which is unwanted. Try to experiment with and without it.